# What does “wardrobe’s worth” mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> We sport an entire wardrobe’s worth of Live Strong bracelets advertising our moderately priced opposition to everything from breast cancer to global warming.

The sentence is a quote from this article:
http://essay.blogs.nytimes.com/2007/09/27/the-college-pastiche/comment-page-14/?_r=0

Comment: It means you can get a different bracelet for every outfit in your wardrobe.

Comment: As it's a US article, it probably means one per outfit. If the article had been written in the UK it could also be read like that or, more likely, as a large cupboard full.

Comment: It means that they've got a bunch of the things that they're trying to unload, now that Armstrong has fallen from grace.  They weren't able to sell them sooner because they don't know how to write proper ads.

Comment: @HotLicks the article is dated 2007, so I doubt they're still selling the stuff. But who knows...

Answer (score 4):

The ***original*** [image] *[wristband](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livestrong_Foundation#Livestrong_wristband)* is a trademark in yellow:

> The Livestrong wristband is a yellow silicone gel bracelet program
>   launched in May 2004 as a fund-raising item. The bracelet was
>   developed by Nike and its advertising agency, Wieden+Kennedy. The band
>   became a popular fashion item in the United States by the end of the
>   summer of 2004, and appeared on a majority of the contenders at the
>   2004 Tour de France.
>
> *Wikipedia.org*

[image]

The [Livestrong Foundation's](http://www.livestrong.org/) yellow wristband promotion for cancer was so popular that the [free market](http://www.discountmugs.com/product/swbw-promotional-swirl-silicone-wristbands/?quantity=20&color=bulk&mm_campaign=5240BD079F071097F942AE10B4D031E2&mm_keyword=89765530701&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=89765530701&utm_content=63865185261&utm_campaign=(PLA)%20Shopping%20Categories%20Promotional&gclid=CjwKEAjwuoOpBRCSy6yQm66J1g8SJABrXW48wmBApk4ED5shrHDKGo6O-Ye5EvkpVZgfGuu0_FTBKhoCsQfw_wcB&kwid=productads-plaid%5E89765530701-sku%5ESWBW@ADL4Bulk@ADL420-adType%5EPLA-device%5Ec-adid%5E63865185261) jumped in with an almost endless combination of colors, designs and messages. Although these are not official Livestrong products, the bracelets of that style are colloquially referred to as Livestrong bracelets.

[image]

The author writes:

> We sport an entire wardrobe’s worth of Live Strong bracelets
>   advertising our moderately priced opposition to everything from breast
>   cancer to global warming

The meaning seems to be that regardless of the issues we want to advocate, and whatever outfits we have in our wardrobes, we have a "livestrong bracelet" in a color and design to match.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. As a non-native speaker, this sentence still seems to confuse me. For example, what dose the word "Wardrobe" mean in this sentence. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @stewiegriffin ScotM's answer explains it well. People have wardrobes full of clothes, in different colours for different occasions. There is a cheap "rubber" wristband for every conceivable outfit you might possess in your ***closet*** (AmEng) / ***wardrobe*** (BrEng).